# R: ggplot2: plot initiating at the axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to respond to a reviewer that wants some changes to a figure... I am using ggplot2 to generate Kaplan-Meier curves, and the reviewer wants the X-axis to start at 0. The default in ggkmTable adds some space between 0 and the Y-axis. I can't figure out what to change to make it look right.
Here is my code:

```
ggkmTable <- function(sfit, table=TRUE,returns = FALSE,
xlabs = "Time in Years", ylabs = "Survival Probability",
ystratalabs = NULL, ystrataname = NULL,
timeby = 100, main = "Kaplan-Meier Plot",
pval = TRUE, ...) {
    require(plyr)
    require(ggplot2)
    require(survival)
    require(gridExtra)
    if(is.null(ystratalabs)) {
        ystratalabs <- as.character(levels(summary(sfit)$strata))
    }
    m <- max(nchar(ystratalabs))
    if(is.null(ystrataname)) ystrataname <- "Strata"
    times <- seq(0, max(sfit$time), by = timeby)
    .df <- data.frame(time = sfit$time, n.risk = sfit$n.risk,
    n.event = sfit$n.event, surv = sfit$surv, strata = summary(sfit, censored = T)$strata,
    upper = sfit$upper, lower = sfit$lower)
    levels(.df$strata) <- ystratalabs
    zeros <- data.frame(time = 0, surv = 1, strata = factor(ystratalabs, levels=levels(.df$strata)),
    upper = 1, lower = 1)
    .df <- rbind.fill(zeros, .df)
    d <- length(levels(.df$strata))
    p <- ggplot(.df, aes(time, surv, group = strata)) +
    geom_step(aes(linetype = strata), size = 0.7) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_x_continuous(xlabs, breaks = times, limits = c(0, max(sfit$time))) +
    scale_y_continuous(ylabs, limits = c(0, 1)) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA)) +
    labs(linetype = ystrataname) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 1, .5, ifelse(m < 10, 1.5, 2.5)), "lines")) +
    ggtitle(main)
    if(pval) {
        sdiff <- survdiff(eval(sfit$call$formula), data = eval(sfit$call$data))
        pval <- pchisq(sdiff$chisq, length(sdiff$n)-1, lower.tail = FALSE)
        pvaltxt <- paste("p =", signif(pval, 3))
        p <- p + annotate("text", x = 0.6 * max(sfit$time), y = 0.1, label = pvaltxt)
    }

    ## Create a blank plot for place-holding
    ## .df <- data.frame()
    blank.pic <- ggplot(.df, aes(time, surv)) +
    geom_blank() +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank())
    if(table) {
        ## Create table graphic to include at-risk numbers
        risk.data <- data.frame(strata = summary(sfit, times = times, extend = TRUE)$strata,
        time = summary(sfit, times = times, extend = TRUE)$time,
        n.risk = summary(sfit, times = times, extend = TRUE)$n.risk)
        data.table <- ggplot(risk.data, aes(x = time, y = strata, label = format(n.risk, nsmall = 0))) +
        #, color = strata)) +
        geom_text(size = 3.5) +
        theme_bw() +
        scale_y_discrete(breaks = as.character(levels(risk.data$strata)), labels = ystratalabs) +
        # scale_y_discrete(#format1ter = abbreviate,
        # breaks = 1:3,
        # labels = ystratalabs) +
        scale_x_continuous("Numbers at risk", limits = c(0, max(sfit$time))) +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, vjust = 1), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 1))
        data.table <- data.table + theme(legend.position = "none") +
        xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
        data.table <- data.table +
        theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1.5, 1, 0.1, ifelse(m < 10, 2.5, 3.5)-0.28 * m), "lines"))
        ## Plotting the graphs
        ## p <- ggplotGrob(p)
        ## p <- addGrob(p, textGrob(x = unit(.8, "npc"), y = unit(.25, "npc"), label = pvaltxt,
        ## gp = gpar(fontsize = 12)))
        grid.arrange(p, blank.pic, data.table,
        clip = FALSE, nrow = 3, ncol = 1,
        heights = unit(c(2, .1, .25),c("null", "null", "null")))
        if(returns) {
            a <- arrangeGrob(p, blank.pic, data.table, clip = FALSE,
            nrow = 3, ncol = 1, heights = unit(c(2, .1, .25),c("null", "null", "null")))
            return(a)
        }
    }
    else {
        ## p <- ggplotGrob(p)
        ## p <- addGrob(p, textGrob(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.23, "npc"),
        ## label = pvaltxt, gp = gpar(fontsize = 12)))
        print(p)
        if(returns) return(p)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer first, then an explanation.

Add the line:

`coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(sfit$time)))`

to your ggplot object.

A simple example:

```html
df <- data.frame(c(runif(10,0,1)),runif(10,0,1))
names(df) <- c("x","y")

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0),
                     labels=c("0","0.25","0.5","0.75","1.0"))
p
```

gives you

[image: plot with undesired x-axis bounds]

whereas, if you add to the above code

```html
p <- p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1))
p
```

you get

[image: the exact x-axis bounds you wanted!]

`coord_cartesian()` is a friend of yours (and anyone who uses your code after you) IFF you are absolutely certain any [visually important] data will never fall beyond the bounds you set within that very function. This is well documented; see [Hadley's doc on this useful creature](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_cartesian.html)

To apply it to your code above and visualize it myself... I need to know what "sfit" is (as per user Pascal's insightful inquiry), likely among other idiosyncratic things. But the gist is:

`scale_x_continuous` (and its sisters `scale_y_continuous` et al.) don't hard-cut bounds to the EXACT parameters you specify. They do as the name implies, yes, "scale" axes according to a function (e.g. log10). But they always leave a cute little buffer around the limits, for assumed aesthetically preferential defaults.

'coord_cartesian`, on the other hand, DOES set axes limits EXACTLY as you specify, cutting out all space and data falling outside those bounds without altering the analyses pertaining to that entire data field. But don't take my word for it: read Hadley's apt description:

"The Cartesian coordinate system is the most familiar, and common, type of coordinate system. Setting limits on the coordinate system will zoom the plot (like you're looking at it with a magnifying glass), and will not change the underlying data like setting limits on a scale will."

To be clear, you can use both `scale_x_continuous` (and y) and `coord_cartesian` in the same ggplot object, because they do different things. The former sets breaks and labels for those breaks, the latter the frame (i.e. visual bounds) of the plot.

The other (dirty, dirty) solution is... photoshop. :(

Comment: Cheers sc_evans! coord_cartesian() works like a charm. For info sfit is a dataframe from the survfit function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
scale_x_continuous("Numbers at risk", limits = c(0, max(sfit$time)), expand = c(0, 0))
```

The expand can also be used on your y-axis if needed.